# Automatic map generating using data (C#)

Tags: c#, .net, lego-mindstorms

I am doing school project using EV3 LEGO robot programmed in C# and connected with Visual Studio by MonoBrick library. I would like to make a map of robot movement (like on the picture 1)([1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/REaYt.jpg)) using some .NET solutions. I wrote program which shows how long should the line be and which turn was taken. Is there any possibility to generate map like this automatically?

Comment: Depends on your movement data structure (distance, turn) and how easily it will map into one of the common vector graphics markup dialects.

Comment: Well that's wonderful, I just put an example together using Graphics for you, and it's closed.

Comment: @Aaron Closing as duplicate is obviously wrong here - if any reason, it would bordering "too broad" or "asking for tool".